# MongoDB - How to map a collection from a lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pipeline

I would like to put the note with the corresponding item, I am close... but just can't figure out to do the final "matching" to get the notes with the right item.

For example:

The "Water" item should have "Water note 1" but not "Fire note 1".

The "Fire" item should have "Fire note 1" but not "Water note 1".

[image: example of notes not going where they need to go]

Here are my data sets:

Inspections:

```
{
  "_id": {"$oid": "635c37d00017b0adec605f01" },
  "REF_InspectionItems": [
    {"$oid": "635c37d30017b0adec605f1d" },
    {"$oid": "635c37d60017b0adec605f34" }
  ]
}
```

InspectionItems:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "635c37d30017b0adec605f1d"},
    "name": "Water",
    "REF_InspectionItemNotes": [
      {"$oid": "635c37d40017b0adec605f26" },
      {"$oid": "635c37d50017b0adec605f2c" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "635c37d60017b0adec605f34"},
    "name": "Fire",
    "REF_InspectionItemNotes": [
      {"$oid": "635c37d70017b0adec605f3d" }
    ]
  }
]
```

InspectionItemNotes:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "635c37d40017b0adec605f26"},
    "text": "Water note 1"
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "635c37d50017b0adec605f2c"},
    "text": "Water note 2"
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "635c37d70017b0adec605f3d"},
    "text": "Fire note 1"
  }
]
```

Pipeline

Here is what I have tried:

```
[
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'inspectionitems', 
      'localField': 'REF_InspectionItems', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'inspectionItemsLookup'
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'inspectionitemnotes', 
      'localField': 'inspectionItemsLookup.REF_InspectionItemNotes', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'inspectionItemNotesLookup'
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'items': {
        '$map': {
          'input': '$inspectionItemsLookup', 
          'as': 'temp', 
          'in': {
            '$mergeObjects': [
              '$$temp', {
                'notes': {
                  '$map': {
                    'input': '$inspectionItemNotesLookup', 
                    'as': 'temp2', 
                    'in': {
                      '$mergeObjects': [
                        '$$temp2', {
                          'thisIsNotShowingUp': {
                            '$first': {
                              '$filter': {
                                'input': '$inspectionItemNotesLookup', 
                                'cond': {
                                  '$eq': [
                                    '$$temp2.REF_InspectionItemNotes', '$$this._id'
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This is what I expect:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to the answer.

The `notes` array which would be appended with `item` object by filtering from the `inspectionItemNotesLookup` array that the document's id is in the `REF_InspectionItemNotes` array.

```
db.inspection.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "inspectionitems",
      "localField": "REF_InspectionItems",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "inspectionItemsLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "inspectionitemnotes",
      "localField": "inspectionItemsLookup.REF_InspectionItemNotes",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "inspectionItemNotesLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      items: {
        $map: {
          input: "$inspectionItemsLookup",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$item",
              {
                notes: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$inspectionItemNotesLookup",
                    cond: {
                      $in: [
                        "$$this._id",
                        "$$item.REF_InspectionItemNotes"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "REF_InspectionItems",
      "inspectionItemsLookup",
      "inspectionItemNotesLookup",
      "itemNotes"
    ]
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PXd7fZEht3I)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8017690/yong-shun - thank you I was just one map and a project too many !